# Android alertdialog not centered when keyboard opens

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I have a AlertDialog with a custom view that contains two EditText fields. At some point the dialog is show using the following code:

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder
     .setView(R.layout.dialog)
     .setMessage("message")
     .setPositiveButton("Oke"){ dialog, id -> println("oke")}
     .setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ dialog, id -> println("cancel")}

val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
```

When the user pressed a EditText the SoftKeyboard show up but the Dialog is not being shifted up. I have tried settings the softinputmode of the dialog.window to SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN or SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE like this.

```
dialog.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I've just created new project with code that you provided, and it seems to work fine for me, when the keyboard is shown - the dialog moves up. Maybe your dialog not centered due to some Activity/Fragment settings, or root layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Activity in which the AlertDialog is shown had a translucent status bar theme.

So instead of initializing the builder with the classic AlertDialog.Builder(this) which uses the context's theme, you can use a dialog theme with no translucent status bar to it:

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar)
```

This theme ensures compatibility with pre-lollipop devices too, but other ones like `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog` should do the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad made a mistake in my example. forgot the window part.